# Installed but can't run Wine. Command 'wine' not found. (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, wine

Installed wine from command line, but when I tried to check the version it says that Command 'wine' not found.
What do I do next?

```
xx@xx-xx:~$ sudo apt install wine-stable  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
wine-stable is already the newest version (6.0.2~bionic-1). 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

xx@xx-xx:~$ wine --version

Command 'wine' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install wine-development 
sudo apt install wine-stable

xx@xx-xx:~$ winecfg
winecfg: command not found
```

Comment: Tried `wine-stable` or `winecfg-stable`?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like wine is not installed or it's not setted as Path

it could be fixed like this

#1 Uninstall Wine

for Stable Version:
`sudo apt-get remove wine-stable`

for development version:
`sudo apt-get remove wine-development`

for ubuntu 18.04 you need to set

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' then run "sudo apt update"`

#2 then ReInstall it

for stable version:

`sudo apt-get install winehq-stable`

for development version:

`sudo apt-get install winehq-devel`

Dont forget to do wine-stable to winehq-stable the wine is now winehq

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked

Comment: No problem good to see that worked

Comment: installing just `winehq-stable` helped me. Didn't need the PPA (I think I already have another winehq PPA). I don't get why this whole thread was downvoted.